# How to check rails route presence in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want something like this:

```
if has_route?(:controller => 'posts', :action => 'index')
  ...
```

How I can do this in a view?

---- SOLUTION ----

```
def has_route? options
  Rails.application.routes.routes.map{|route| route.defaults}.include?(options)
end
```

Comment: Are you trying to test this route?

Comment: Yes. I have a hash and I want to check a route existence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is sort of the inverse of what you want, but you can do something like this:

`Rails.application.routes.recognize_path('/posts')`

Which will return a hash like this:

`{:controller=>"posts", :action=>"index"}`

But i don't know of an API for giving it the hash and returning the path.

You could look through the [ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.0.0/ActionDispatch/Routing/RouteSet) API.

Also, note that `Rails.application.routes.routes` returns an Array of Journey::Routes objects, so you could `map` this array for the controller/action pairing you want.  But it seems like this API should already exist.  If not, perhaps it should.  :)

Comment: I already looked it, unfortunately I didnt find an inverse method for recognize_path.

Comment: write one and do a pull request.  :)

Comment: Yep. I find the solution, thanks. Rails.application.routes.routes.map{|route| route.defaults}.include?({:controller => 'posts', :action => 'index'}) ---> true

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like `respond_to?("[name of rails routing method]")`

Comment: How to check a hash, not a string and not a method existance :)

Comment: The intent is actually to check the existence of the rails method based on a route (such as controller_action_path()), but I see what you're saying.  You could create a helper function that wraps url_for([your hash]) and catches a Routing Error.  If there is an error, no path exists, otherwise, it does.

Comment: I already thought about it, but hoped that there is a ready solution.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the routes test in this way

```
it "routes to #index" do
  get("/projects").should route_to("projects#index")
end
```

The scaffold for resource will generate the spec file for testing routes, for example you can look [here](https://github.com/sevenmaxis/task_manager/blob/master/spec/routing/projects_routing_spec.rb)

Comment: My question for usage in a view, not for testing with rspec. I want use this to DRY my views.